# trouble with making the style of the tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I develop tab bar application and each tab view is a table view. So my problem is that in first tab I developed a plain table view, but in the second one I need a grouped one. I changed in the xib the style to grouped and in method did this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

But the simulator still shows me a plain table view. When I tried to write the same code in a new app - everything worked fine. Can anyone help and explain why it doesn't work?

The whole code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *row1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aaa1", @"aaa2", @"aaa3", nil];
    NSArray *row2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bbb1", @"bbb2", @"bbb3", nil];
    NSArray *row3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ccc1", @"ccc2", @"ccc3", nil];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          row1, @"a",
                          row2, @"b",
                          row3, @"c", nil];
    self.list = dict;


    NSArray *array = [[list allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.keys = array;
    [row1 release];
    [row2 release];
    [row3 release];
    [dict release];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section]; 
    NSArray *nameSection = [list objectForKey:key];
    return [nameSection count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:section]; 
    NSArray *nameSection = [self.list objectForKey:key];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:section]; 
    return key;
}
```

Actually nothing, that I change in attributes inspector in XIB file seem to work. can anyone help?

Comment: did you implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods? and do you have the number of sections to be >1 for it to appear grouped?please provide more code. And what is the point of if(self)?

Comment: if (self) is a provided code when selecting that the new view controller shall be a table view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your class is a `UITableViewController` since you are using:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
```

### Example

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSString * something;
}

@end
```

### Alternatively

If this is **not** your rootViewController, you can always make sure the table is grouped by:

```
MyViewController * mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Comment: I checked - my class is UITableViewController

Comment: In which method exactly should I put the latter?